# synchronising folders in thunderbird 14

Tags: synchronization, imap, pop3, thunderbird

I use thunderbird 14.0 and I make quite a lot of topic-specific folders in my local thunderbird client. I want them to be available in the mail server, but I don't know how to set this option in my thunderbird.

I read https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization and according to it, there should be a `Synchronisation & Storage` settings section, which is unavailable at my client. When I go into the `Server Settings`, the server type is hardcoded to `POP`. I can't it to be `IMAP`, dunno why...

Answer (score 0):

IMAP service should be supported by your mail provider. 
POP does-not supports mail synchronization from clients to server.

IMAP is usally a paid service except for gmail(i know) ask your mail provider for further information.

> the server type is hardcoded to POP. I can't it to be IMAP, dunno why...

thats the profile that you have configured, if you know the imap settings try create a new profile with imap settings.